# phpmyadmin is not opening in Wampserver?

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdBof.png)Phpmyadmin is not opening in wampserver during login with the user name root and password blank and previously it was working but currently not working. Please check screenshot...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9fPm.png

Comment: any error you get ?

Comment: what's an error message?

Comment: Cannot log in to the MySQL server this message I am getting

Comment: @Dilek getting this message - Cannot log in to the MySQL server...please have a look the screenshot

Comment: @VikashPandey I am not able to see images from i.stack.imgur.com can you upload some where else ?

Comment: Are you sure that the MySQL service is started?